# Ember router construction - App.Router.create undefined (with ember-rails)

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to get Ember working in an existing Rails app, so install the `ember-rails` gem. It gave me a `app.js` based on [this generator template](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails/blob/master/lib/generators/templates/app.js) that contains

```
var router = App.router = App.Router.create({
  enableLogging: true,
  location: 'hash'
});

App.initialize(router);
```

I also wanted to use `ember-data`, and saw some posts saying edge is the only way to go with that. So so updated both `ember-data` and `ember.js` itself to edge.

So when I run this, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined` on the `App.Router.create` line.

I'm guessing that the API has changed and this is obsolete, but can't find the current canonical way of creating this router object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples here are canonical AFAIK: http://emberjs.com/guides/outlets/

...except that `Ember.State` should be `Ember.Route` now. But this is what you want to do:

```
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  enableLogging: true,
  location: 'hash'
});

App.initialize();
```

Comment: I did have `Ember.Router.extend` in another file to set up the routes. But based on what you sent it looks like `App.initialize()` does not actually need a router object passed to it at all. And so I took that out and guess what no more error. thanks :)

Comment: If that was all you changed, I worry that logging isn't enabled (is this true?), since `App.router` is created but not used. I could be wrong, but I think what you want to do to set those params in this case is `App.Router.reopen({...})`

Comment: well `App.Router` is part of `App` so it can be used theoretically. But I don't know if `enableLogging` does anything yet. It shows up in a lot of example code but I don't see any console output. Are there any docs for `Ember.Router`?

Comment: Not sure if you noticed I was referring to the lowercase App.router. In any case this is the best source of Router documentation for now: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/tree/master/packages

Comment: Whoops, here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/lib/router.js